# Suddenly getCurrentUser() returns null and I got access denied from realtime database on firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, refresh-token

I built an android TV application using java, and I'm using firebase auth with email and password.
I am uploading data to firebase realtime database periodically every 10 seconds, it is working fine, but some time I start facing permission denied, and when try to call `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` it returns null. some times it takes one day to get this message, sometimes it required 2 hours. and I am unable to get the reason for that issue, and how to resolve it. Anyone can help me with it?

Thanks